# Detect consequitive minutes in POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct

Suppose I have

```
dt <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-01-01 09:30:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:31:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:35:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:36:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:37:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:40:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:50:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:51:00", 
                   "2020-01-01 09:52:00"))
```

and I want to find the first minute for every time say 3 consecutive minutes are in `dt`, i.e.

```
"2020-01-01 09:35:00" "2020-01-01 09:50:00".
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach -

```
with(rle(as.integer(c(difftime(dt[-1],dt[-length(dt)],units = 'mins'),0)) == 1), 
    dt[!duplicated(rep(seq_along(values), lengths)) & 
        rep(lengths >= 2 & values, lengths)])

#[1] "2020-01-01 09:35:00 +08" "2020-01-01 09:50:00 +08"
```

- `difftime` calculates difference between consecutive timestamps.
- Using `rle` we calculate lengths whose difference between timestamp is 1 minute.
- Return only the starting timestamp of groups where length is greater than 2.